# Conditional Formatting using date criteria

Tags: excel-formula

I have this formula as a conditional format that highlights certain cells that meet the date requirements. I just want to add an extra criteria that highlights as well if the date=today. Seems simple but I cannot get the syntax right.

Can anyone help, please?

Current Formula:

```
=AND(ISNUMBER(SEARCH("Condo",K11)),OR(AND(WEEKDAY(TODAY())>= 3,WEEKDAY(TODAY())<=6,INT(X11)=INT(TODAY()-1)),AND(WEEKDAY(TODAY())=2,INT(X11)>=INT(TODAY()-3),INT(X11)<=INT(TODAY()-1))))
```

Comment: you can have more than one condition per cell.  rather than over complicating a single formula as a catch all, you may want to consider simplifying the formula and breaking it into multiple conditions.  Additionally this would allow for different formats to be set if so desired.

Comment: Workbook /google sheets example would've been great mate

Answer (score 0):

First off, consider this topic for basic examples of how to review your own code, may come in handy in future! ☺. You can find this post [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67731486/13607672).

**Google Sheets**: [here](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1o0yri0NTYZxYeW2WFWFRgN5UT9yjs_jw5WOMHgnrivo/edit?usp=sharing)

**Screenshot**

[image: Screenshot of Google Sheets (for reference)]

**Component | assessment**

(note: my column E represents what you have in column X, and likewise my column F is what you 'appear' to have in K).

| Function | Interpretation, possible issues/remedy |
| --- | --- |
| 1. K11 includes 'Condo' | Case of word (try: `search("condo", lower(K11))` etc. to mitigate errors if case is unimportant |
| 2. Weekday | `Weekday(today())` defaults to 1 if today() = Sunday. If you're expecting 7 instead, use weekday(date,2). |
| AND{3-4} where: |  |
| 3. OR - first 'AND' |  |
| 3a. `WEEKDAY(TODAY())>=3` | Weekday ('today()') = Tue-Fri (incl.) F3 must be day before |
| 4. OR - second 'AND' |  |
| 4a. `WEEKDAY(TODAY())`=2 | Weekday (today) = Mon AND |
| 4b. `INT(F3)>=INT(TODAY()-3` | F3 must be Sun |

**Conclusion:**

a) Suspect you were intending to be using Weekday(date,2)

b) Default for 'weekday(date)' returns following weekdays:

[image: Default Weekday() function]

c) HOWEVER, judging from the 2nd AND statement:

```
INT(F3)>=INT(TODAY()-3)
```

includes possibility of having negative weekdays(!)

d) fyi : you don't need to include 'INT' everywhere, you should be able to simply reference the dates, Excel will figure out the rest (i.e. will automatically use serial code when taking differences, adding 3 days etc.).