# Excel formula to check for text part 2

Tags: excel, excel-formula, formula

Adding on to a question I asked yesterday, I am getting a "There's a problem with this formula" error in Excel.

I am using the following formula:

```
=IF(OR(AD9834="In progress",BB9834="",ROUND(BW1-AI9834,0),IF(AD9834="Reopened",ROUND(BW1-AP9834,0),(BW1-AI9834,0))))
```

I just need a second set of eyes because I am not seeing where the error is located.

Comment: `=IF(OR(AD9834="In progress",BB9834=""),ROUND($BW$1-AI9834,0),IF(AD9834="Reopened",ROUND(BW1-AP9834,0),ROUND(BW1-AI9834,0)))` presumably. Missing a closing `)` for the `OR`, as well as the last instance of `ROUND`. Can be simplified.

Answer (score 1):

Solution is quick and I cover this in first few lines that follow.  Have also expanded by highlighting a few tips/tricks I use to audit my own (and my teams'/others' excel workbooks/models etc.). Trust in order (flag any Qs you may have in this regard as req.)..

Ta,

### Summary of changes

1. Include bracket to close OR statement in first / outer IF statement
2. Include 'Round' in final part of function

### Corrected Function:

```
=IF(OR(AD9834="In progress",BB9834=""),ROUND(BW1-AI9834,0),IF(AD9834="Reopened",ROUND(BW1-AP9834,0),ROUND(BW1-AI9834,0)))
```

### Auditing tips/identification routine

When auditing / validating a function (especially long ones like this), I like to:

**(a) Use function assistant popup window**

- Click on each of the components of the function that appear in the little popup window when you enter the function
- This will highlight the corresponding part of the code in the function window.

I'm talking about this popup in your case:
[image]

You can drag it around the window, e.g. here I've placed at the bottom of the function window / toolbar:

[image: Popup assistant featuring at bottom of function window/dialogue toolbar]

For instance, in screenshot below, I've clicked on 'logical test' part of the IF statement, and could immediately see where you've gone wrong - as the "logical test" component of the IF statement corresponded to your *entire* equation - i.e. you've obviously missed a comma or bracket somewhere to separate out 'value if True' and 'value if False' components:

[image: Logical test component]

**(b) Simplify by creating 'test' function**

Inserting the first bracket, and simplifying for the moment by referencing cells A1, B1 instead of A100095, B214032 etc., I repeat the 'click component' routine for the next sub-function (your OR statement).

**(c) Evaluate sub-functions within function:**

I also like to highlight the various 'sub-functions' and evaluate them (press f9 - but be careful not to press 'enter' as it will embed/overwrite test function, instead press ctrl+Z to reverse the evaluation) within the function window/toolbar to see which ones are working/broken.

Doing so simplifies checking the long function you have to something that looks like this:

[image: Simplifying when auditing]

i.e.
*step 1: highlight sub-function like the OR statement:**

[image: Step 1]

*step 2: press F9 to temporarily evaluate:*

[image: Step 2: f9: temporary evaluation]

*step 3: repeat for each 'sub-function'*

As I've fixed this item, no errors upon evaluation, I move onto next sub-function and eventually end up with an error when trying to evaluate your final if statement:

[image: step 3:]

step 4: repeat above for each sub-function of 'parent' sub-function

- In this case, your 2nd IF statement, comprising 'children' = logical test, true / false sections of IF statement)...
  *step 4: cancel out by pressing escape*

Doing so quickly allows me to identify your missing 'round' statement (I imagine it's this you intended to have) right at the end of the function.

**(d) Check brackets**
Penultimate step is to check opening and closing brackets - to ensure you have applied these correctly. Don't go with Excel's auto-fix proposal that sometimes pops up:

[image: Auto-fix popup: never accept this!☺]

**(e) Apply changes to original function as required**

Finally, I manually adjust the original function according to the errors identified using the 'cut-down' temporary 'test function' created above.

This leads to the following proposal for you to conveniently 'copy and paste' in the relevant / applicable cell:

(see up top)..

Ciao,

J